# Index page bug while using a filter

Tags: bug, new-nav

**Issue** : A new specific page is not shown and if i open it using page index (at the bottom ) from **a tab using one tag as a filter**.

**Issue description** : if i open-up a page **(** let's a 5th page and current tab has only one tag as a filter ,not more than one **)** from the "go-to page indexes"(at the bottom) using

**"right click" = > "select Open link in new tab"** , then it just open the first page and even on the new tab if you click on 5th page index , it will take you to the top as shown in image below

[image]

**Step to produce issue :**

1. Either open new tab and apply any single filter let's say `r` or choose saved tab with single filter (make sure to refresh to see the accurate issue)
2. Go at the bottom "goto any page index"  . let's say 5th index page using
3. Right click = > select "Open link in new tab"
4. In new tab you will see same first page and again if you press 5th page , it will take you at the top.

It's works fine :

- if you have more than one filter tag
- if you simply use the tab without any filter